# WatchKit Extension with Coredata Syncing Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, watchkit

I'm making an app for the Apple Watch with WatchKit.

I have a single NSManagedObject that both the app on the phone and the app on the watch get their data from. There should only ever be one object of this type in the database so both targets should be accessing the same object in the store, though obviously not the same instance.

This is all working fine, they can both read this object perfectly well, using an App Group to share the SQL file. The problem is, when the app makes a change to the object I want the watch to pick this up straight away so it can update its interface.

I'm using MMWormhole to send a notification to the watch when the object is saved, when this happens I then do a new fetch on the context in the extension. However, when I do this fetch, none of the data on the object has changed in the extension to reflect the state of the object in the app. It's still exactly as it was before the save was called in the app.

So firstly, is there a way of being notified in the extension of CoreData saves in the app without having to use MMWormhole? But more importantly  what am I doing wrong to end up with old data in my subsequent fetch request in the extension? I would have thought doing a fetch on a context would query the store, and as both apps are pointed to the same db file it would pick up the new data. Is there a delay after saving, are fetch requests cached somehow or am I just misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use NSManagedContext refreshObject to update your object.  Since the extension and the iOS app run in different memory spaces you will need to use something like MMWormhole for notifications.  See this for more info [Core Data with WatchKit and iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802719/core-data-with-watchkit-and-ios-app/28814153#28814153)